# Problem with Installing Mobile Partner errors

Tags: ubuntu-touch, modem

This is the error I get now.Although I had previously installed it and it worked fine.

```
   install: line 310: [: -ne: unary operator expected
    install: line 317: [: -ne: unary operator expected
    install: line 324: [: -gt: unary operator expected
    install: line 329: [: -lt: unary operator expected
    install: line 337: [: -gt: unary operator expected
    install: line 342: [: -lt: unary operator expected
    install: line 350: [: -gt: unary operator expected
    install: line 355: [: -lt: unary operator expected
The software is exist. Do you want overwrite it? ([Y]/N):y
mkdir: missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.

Can not create dir: 

Finished, press any key to exit
```

Here is the source for install script:
http://shrib.com/mp21

Answer (score 0):

As its saying that software already existed , If you say yes again it have recreate a dir for it and thats the point where you getting the error. So dont say yes at that step and try it.

hope that helps.